# Gaining access to /User/Library/Container/<identifier> in Sandbox

Tags: swift, macos, sandbox, nsopenpanel

I am developing an app and I want access to the `/User/<username>/Library/Containers` folder to read some data.

When iterating over the files, no data is returned until I open a `NSOpenPanel` on that specific location. That behavior is to be expected, because the app is sandboxed.

I have another app installed that is called "AppManager" (sandboxed, available in the App Store). The app also reads data from that folder, but I only have to open the `NSOpenPanel` on the `/Applications` folder.

I read about the `FileManager` method `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:` which seems to be a good starting point, but somehow this method is not available?

How (if possible) can a sandboxed app gain access to `/User/<username>/Library/Containers` without opening a `NSOpenPanel`? Can I gain access to more than one directory by opening only one `NSOpenPanel`?

Regards,
Sascha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do anything without the `NSOpenPanels` or dragging directories on your app - this is a security measure so the App Store apps don't trash data that doesn't belong to them

I saw programs ask the user to just select `/` in `NSOpenPanel` to get access to the whole drive. Again it is better to just ask for what you really need as you may not get past review. Some apps just have a separate UI to ask the user to `NSOpenPanel` some directories for them and don't continue until you do.

Comment: Hello, I also prefer this method. I was just curious how the specified App does that. It asks for /Applications and gets access to /Users/<username>/Library.

Comment: Maybe the app is old (pre-sandboxing) or maybe it just reads its own container (you always have the access to that)

Comment: The latest update was released last year, so it is sandboxed (or else it would not need to show a dialog anyways) and the app deletes files from those directories, so it has full access outside to /Library/ of its own container. Pretty Strange.

Comment: https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/360w0d1E430A1G1M1w1L/Screen%20Shot%202017-04-15%20at%2019.25.28.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=1193270 I downloaded the app and it asks me for my home directory first, then it asks for `/Applications`. You must have missed it

Comment: When I open the app, it asks for Applications. Must be the NSOpenSavePanelDelegate that handles this behavior.